# c how do you pass pointer by reference and increase the value

Tags: c

I know its a stupid question, but any help here is appreciated :)

So I want to pass the pointer by reference in `C`, and would like to increase the value

```
""""""""""File: stat.h""""""""""""""""""
typedef struct
{
    uint16_t  Stat;
}S_Stats_t;

""""""""""File: stat.c""""""""""""""""""
static S_Stats_t C_Signal =
{
    .Stat = 0x0001,
};

// Get the stat
const S_Stats_t* D_GetSignal(void)
{
    return &C_Signal;
}

// increment stat
void D_SetStat(S_Stats_t* pPointer)
{
    pPointer=pPointer+UINT16_C(0x0001);
}

""""""""""File: main.c""""""""""""""""""
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stat.h>

int main()
{
    // Get the current stat
    const S_Stats_t* const pSignal = D_GetSignal();
    // increment the stat
    D_SetStat(&pSignal->Stat);
    // Print the new stats
    printf("incremented Counter value, n:0x%x - %u.\n",pSignal->Stat,pSignal->Stat);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're on the right track (except maybe with the consts). What error messages do you get? Do they make sense to you?

Comment: I am not getting any error message, but if i add a printf in the D_SetStat it shows "'incremented Counter value, n:0xc7216b18 - 3340856088.'" this is not what I want to do, and the printf statement in the main.c shows "'incremented Counter value, n:0x1 - 1.'" so there is actually no change

Comment: Yes, that looks better now. You can also write `pPointer+=UINT16_C(0x0001);`, that is shorter and has the same effect.

Comment: There is no reference in `C`, there is pointer to pointer only or address of pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not very clear what you want to do but I'm assuming that you want to increment the **Stat** member of the **C_Signal** struct, by passing the pointer to the struct.

First of all, if you want to modify the value, you should remove the **const** qualifier. The const qualifier should be applied to the declaration of any variable to specify that its value will not be changed.

In the **D_SetStat** function, you want to increment the **Stat** member, not the struct pointer.

**stat.h**

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct
{
    uint16_t  Stat;
}S_Stats_t;


S_Stats_t* D_GetSignal(void);


void D_SetStat(S_Stats_t* pPointer);
```

**stat.c**

```
#include "stat.h"

static S_Stats_t C_Signal =
{
    .Stat = 0x0001,
};

// Get the stat
S_Stats_t* D_GetSignal(void)
{
    return &C_Signal;
}

// Increment stat
void D_SetStat(S_Stats_t* pPointer)
{
    pPointer->Stat += (uint16_t)0x0001;
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "stat.h"

int main(void)
{
    // Get the current stat
    S_Stats_t* pSignal = D_GetSignal();
    // Increment the stat
    D_SetStat(pSignal);
    // Print the new stats
    printf("incremented Counter value, n:0x%x - %u.\n",pSignal->Stat,pSignal->Stat);

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**

I don't know why you need to keep the **const** qualifier.
It doesn't make much sense to modify a **const** variable and it will be discarded by the compiler anyway. You can avoid the warning message by making the explicit cast (see below).

**stat.h**

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct
{
    uint16_t  Stat;
}S_Stats_t;


const S_Stats_t* D_GetSignal(void);


void D_SetStat(uint16_t* pPointer);
```

**stat.c**

```
#include "stat.h"

static S_Stats_t C_Signal =
{
    .Stat = 0x0001,
};

// Get the stat
const S_Stats_t* D_GetSignal(void)
{
    return &C_Signal;
}

// Increment stat
void D_SetStat(uint16_t* pPointer)
{
    *pPointer += (uint16_t)0x0001;
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "stat.h"

int main(void)
{
    // Get the current stat
    const S_Stats_t* const pSignal = D_GetSignal();
    // Increment the stat
    D_SetStat(&((S_Stats_t*)pSignal)->Stat);
    // Print the new stats
    printf("incremented Counter value, n:0x%x - %u.\n",pSignal->Stat,pSignal->Stat);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: sorry I have a typo in my code I actually want to pass the `&pSignal->Stat` in the function `D_SetStat(&pSignal->Stat);`. But I can not remove the `const`

Comment: Hi, thanks but I actually want to pass  `&pSignal->Stat` in the function `D_SetStat(&pSignal->Stat);`  as I have > 30 members in `C_Signals struct `

Comment: You just need to change the **D_SetStat** argument type and pass the **Stat** variable address instead. I've edited my answer again.

Comment: it works fine, but I am looking for some optimized way of doing it. But thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Changing `D_SetStat` function to have parameter of a pointer of type `uint16_t` and then derefence and incrementing it seems to work.

```c
void D_SetStat(uint16_t* pPointer)
{
    *pPointer += UINT16_C(0x0001);
}
```

But getting a warning for const declaration:

```
warning: passing argument 1 of 'D_SetStat' discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
```

**Update:**

After declaring a constant pointer to constant, you cannot change what it's pointing at nor it's value later, [as said here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/const-qualifier-in-c/).

Though I'm not clear whether this answers your question, you can change `D_SetStat` function in the following way.

As you have many members in `S_Stats_t` struct, pass an `int` to `D_SetStat` function and it'll update the corresponding member.

```c
void D_SetStat(uint16_t number)
{
    switch(number)
    {
        case 0: // Incrementing C_Signal.Stat, assuming Stat is the 0th member
            C_Signal.Stat += UINT16_C(0x0001);
            break;
        case 1: // Update other members
            ...
            ...
        default: // In case an unknown number is passed
            ...
    }
}
```

And then in `main` function call `D_SetStat` like this:

```c
    D_SetStat(0); // The member number you want to update
```

Comment: excatly, can we somehow get rid of the warning message

Comment: You are assigning pSignal a pointer to C_Signal in main() function. So, calling D_SetStat(&pSignal->Stat) is same as incrementing C_Signal.Stat. So, why not use a function that'll directly increment C_Signal?

Comment: yes, it is possible but I have > 30 members in C_Signals struct and I do not want to create 30 functions!

Comment: @OmChoudhary please see my updated answer above. Also consider clarifying your question.

Comment: it works fine, but I am looking for some optimized way of doing it. But thanks for your efforts.